# C# Partial Class and COM Interface

Tags: c#, partial-classes, com-interface

I'm creating a C# library and am going to expose a COM interface to it.

I understand the steps requried to do this, i.e.

1. Ensure assumbly GUID is assigned, e.g:
   `[assembly: Guid("dde7717b-2b75-4972-a4eb-b3d040c0a182")]`
2. Ensure COMVibile attribute is True
3. Put a GUID attribute on the class, e.g. `[GuidAttribute("4df74b15-d531-4217-af7e-56972e393904")]`
4. Register using Regasm.

My question is this. If I have a partial class defined. Do I need to add the `GuidAttribute` to both these classes?

In fact, thinking about this, I'm guessing this question applies whatever the attribute (e.g. `Serializable`).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you apply an attribute twice to the same class (no matter if in the same file or in two different files) then the class will have the attribute applied twice. A partial class defined in two files is not two classes, it's just one class partially defined in multiple files. So, no, don't repeat the GuidAttribute in each file again.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, even attempting to add it twice results in a failure.

Answer (score 2):

At compile time, attributes of partial-type definitions are merged. For example, the following declarations:

```
[System.SerializableAttribute]
partial class Moon { }

[System.ObsoleteAttribute]
partial class Moon { }
```

are equivalent to:

```
[System.SerializableAttribute]
[System.ObsoleteAttribute]
class Moon { }
```